# Create a PerformancePoint Services App with custom database name via PowerShell

Tags: performancepoint, powershell, installation

It seems [New-SPPerformancePointServiceApplication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608122.aspx) cmdlet does not have -databaseName parameter as other cmdlets to create a service apps. I wonder if it is possible to create PerformancePoint services with custom database name via PowerShell?

If you run this command with the required parameters:

```
New-SPPerformancePointServiceApplication -Name "PerformancePointServices" -ApplicationPool "ServiceAppPool"
```

New Performance Point service app will be created and it's database name will be PerformancePointServices_GUID. I would like to be able to create a database with a custom name (without guid :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry - known issue - for PPS you can't do this. learn to love the GUIDs!

Comment: LOL, if you say so that that's it!
We tried with DB rename and then update with Set-SPPerformancePointServiceApplication but such ServiceApp has problems with updates etc.

Answer (score 1):

Todd Carter's post ["The Wizard Likes His GUIDs"](http://todd-carter.com/post/2010/04/26/The-Wizard-Likes-His-GUIDs.aspx) provides a PowerShell script that is supposed to create GUID-less database names. There is no explicitly set database name in his script but perhaps it uses the service application name?

You might also like to try [AutoSPInstaller](http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/) but I can't see PerformancePoint deployed at all in that.

Comment: Nope the Wizard also uses New-SPPerformancePointServiceApplication that appends GUID. It seems like a deadend to me :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Todd's script doesn't do it, you still end up with a GUID, and according to this blog: [Deploying PerformancePoint 2010 Soup to Nuts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/performancepoint/deploying-performancepoint-2010-soup-to-nuts) it is not possible.

Shame, as I *just can't wait* for the first time I run across a need to install to a managed SQL instance where all databases must be pre-provisioned!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in Service Pack 1. `New-SPPerformancePointServiceApplication` now includes `DatabaseName` and `DatabaseServer` parameters.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608122.aspx